# Can't replace "[" and "]" characters in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace "[" and "]" characters in the string using javascript.

when I'm doing

```
newString = oldString.replace("[]", "");
```

then it works fine - but the problem is I have a lot of this characters in my string and I need to replace all of the occurrences.

But when I'm doing:

```
newString = oldString.replace(/[]/g, "");
```

or

```
newString = oldString.replace(/([])/g, "");
```

nothing is happens. I've also tried with HTML numbers like

```
newString = oldString.replace(/&#91;&#93;/g, "");
```

but it doesn't work neither. Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: And why you can't use regular replace without regexps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either need to escape the opening square bracket, and add a pipe between them:

```
newString = oldString.replace(/\[|]/g, "");
```

Or you need to add them in a character class (square brackets) and escape them both:

```
newString = oldString.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kgdaq8ev/1/)

> "[...there are 12 characters with special meanings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html): the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, and the opening square bracket `[`, the opening curly brace `{`... If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash."

Comment: You screwed up the link. I've fixed it.

Comment: I didn't screw it... It was intended... ;P

Comment: BTW I believe that even when the OP has marked as the right answer, it seems like it's wrong. OP wants to replace `[` and `]`. See other answers where the search is `\[\]` :O

Answer (score 7):

`[]` in a regex is a character class. Since you haven't escaped, them you're saying a "find any of the following characters", and not providing any. Try `/[\[\]]/` instead.

edit: @andy is right. forgot to put in a container `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution :

```
newString = oldString.split("[]").join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

had a similair situation. i just used backslash like so.

```
-replace '\[','' -replace ']',''
```